# std::function<void(std::string&) noexcept> compiler error, want to retain noexcept (C++17)

Tags: c++, c++17

The following code fails unless 'noexcept' is omitted. Is there a way to retain `noexcept` and fix this error?

The error(s):

```
> functional(1479) : error C2027 : use of undefined type 'std::_Get_function_impl<_Fty>'
with
[
    _Fty = void(std::string &) noexcept
]
> functional(1479) : note : see declaration of 'std::_Get_function_impl<_Fty>'
with
[
    _Fty = void(std::string &) noexcept
]
> main.cpp(5) : note : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::function<void (std::string &) noexcept>' being compiled
> functional(1480) : error C2504 : 'type' : base class undefined
[more errors]
> error C2664: 'void bar(functor_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(std::string &) noexcept' to 'functor_t'
```

The code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
typedef function<void(string&) noexcept> functor_t;
void bar(functor_t f) {
    string args{ "a" };
    f(args); 
}
void foo(string& args) noexcept { }
int main() {
    bar(foo);
}
```

This seems like a problem with VC++ and its current version of std library. Aside from removing `noexcept` is there a work-around that will enable this code to work for x64 on Visual C++?

I'm using Visual Studio ver 15.8.7, Windows SDK ver 10.0.17134.0, and vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726 (all latest versions).

Thanks in advance.

Edit #1:

line 1631 of functional:

```
#define _FUNCTION_POINTER_DEDUCTION_GUIDE(CALL_OPT, X1, X2, X3) \
template<class _Ret, \
    class... _Types> \
    function(_Ret (CALL_OPT *)(_Types...)) \
        -> function<_Ret (_Types...)>;  // intentionally discards CALL_OPT
```

It appears that the above code fails to match the signature in x64(?). Can anyone confirm this (I'm new-ish to C++17).

Comment: I've added some of the code from std::function that looks as though it is failing to match the x64 signature (i.e. `CALLOPT` doesn't match when x64 build). I'll keep tinkering.

Comment: You already found the work-around--drop the noexcept in your typedef.  The problem is that std::function does not have a specialization for noexcept, so until the standard changes, you can't expect this to work.

Comment: Not really... this issue means I cannot use `noexcept` since I'm targeting x64 and results in non-trivial rework for my code-base if I need to remove it. That the behaviour is different between x86 and x64 is annoying; I'm trying to write another macro that matches the signature for the x64 build allowing the dropping of the CALL_OPT that is causing the miss-match

Comment: @axon What standard are you using the compile the code against?  I use `latest` and it fails on 32 to 64 bit builds.  The only portable work around is to remove `noexcept` as `std::function` is not designed to work with it.  Either a feature request or defect report is needed to get the standard fixed so the code will actually work.

Comment: I'm also not clear how removing noexcept requires rework in your codebase.  `std::function<void(string&)>` will accept functions both with `noexcept` and without.

Comment: @NathanOliver Cheers. Have verified that my compiler settings didn't match (so x64/x64 make no difference). Am using `/std:c++17` compiler option (`cl.exe`), in part am using C++17 for `constexpr` and `std::byte`.

Comment: @PeterRuderman I want to retain `noexcept` throughout my codebase

Comment: @axon Peter is saying that removing `noexcept` from your `std::function` will already work, and you don't need to remove `noexcept` anywhere else in your codebase.

Comment: It doesn't do you any good to include noexcept in a `std::function` instance because it won't propagate to `operator()`.

Comment: thanks for clarifying CássioRenan and @PeterRuderman .. just working through the code changes and will update (it's used all over the place)

Comment: Haven't found a fix. Have instead propagated non-noexcept as far through my code as needed to compile with C++17. Would strongly prefer to use an implementation of std::function that allows `noexcept`. This is no-longer a blocker and will revisit it later

Comment: If you think this is a MSVC bug, then you can report it as a problem in the menu "Help/Send Feedback/Report a problem…".